# PHP and Window environment based grep

Tags: php, bash, curl, command-line

Hi fellow StackOverflow.

Is it possible for the PHP in the IIS.
What's the function of the PHP is a button.

Once the button is clicked it will show result from the below command :

```
grep "0,100" logs.log -a | wc -l
```

Then it will show the value on the PHP .
Is it possible to do so?

Comment: do you want to execute this command with PHP?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613616/php-exec-on-a-windows-with-iis-configuration

Comment: @SomnathMuluk, because the server that process is far.. It's production based, I don't want them to temper any data. So it's wise to create a page just to view the statistic.

Comment: Tangentially, that's a [useless use of `wc -l`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#wc); POSIX grep would have `grep -c -a "0,100" logs.log`