# How to resolve the PHP Error: exec() unable to fork

Tags: php, iis

I am getting this error/warning PHP exec(): unable to fork ["command I plan on running"] when attempting to run the exec() within a PHP script. It is running on an IIS server. I have attempted the following:

- Changing Authentication settings on IIS server for web site
- giving read/write access to relevant users on cmd.exe
- Scanned the php.ini file for any disables for exec() function

I am running out of clues as to why this error is occurring. versions of the same script are working well on other VMs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613616/php-exec-on-a-windows-with-iis-configuration

Answer (score 1):

Please check these 2 locations:

(1) Application Pool > Advanced Settings > Process Model > Identity

This should be set to a domain user.

(2) Web site > Authentication > Anonymous Authentication
This should be set to the same "Specific user" as the application pool (in 1 above).

After (1) and (2) above, please try running exec() in IIS again (please remember to restart the IIS service before you retry)

Comment: my App requires Basic and Windows Authentication so I have Anonymous Authentication disabled. Is there any solution without changing these settings?